# Integral of shifted function equal to the original function

Tags: calculus

Why is it that $\int_0^Lf(x)\ \mathrm dx$ is the same as $\int_0^Lf(L-x)\ \mathrm dx$.

I was just messing around and found this to be the case for various functions I tested.

Comment: try the substitution $y=L-x$; change the limits and account for $dy$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ g(x)=f(L-x)$$

Observe that
$$g(\frac L2)=f(\frac L2)$$

the curve $ C_g $ of the function $ g $  at $ [0,L] $, is obtained from $ C_f $  by the symetry with respect to the vertical line whose equation is $ x=\frac L2 $.

So, the two curves $ C_f $ and $ C_g $ give the same area, or the same integral.

In other words, with $ t=L-x ,$

$$\int_0^Lf(x)dx=\int_L^0f(L-t)(-1)dt$$
$$=\int_0^Lg(t)dt=\int_0^Lg(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\int_0^L f(x) ~ dx.$$ By the fact that the Lebesgue measure is invariant under translation, this is equal to $$-\int_0^{-L} f(-x) ~ dx.$$ Now define $g(x) = f(-x),$ so $$-\int_0^{-L} f(-x) ~ dx = -\int_0^{-L} g(x) ~ dx = -\int_L^{0} g(x + L) ~ dx = \int_0^{L} g(x + L) ~ dx.$$ But notice that $g(x + L) = f(L - x)$ from our definition of $g$, so $$\int_0^{L} g(x + L) ~ dx = \int_0^L f(L - x) ~ dx.$$